# how to use rubinius to compile rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubinius

I have a rails application, I want to compile it using rubinius and distribute the compiled code only ?
is that possible using rubinius since I've not seen any good tutorials about how to use it with rails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand You want to deploy Your server-side Rails application as a single binary file?
I think it's not possible with Rubinius or MRI. Your better bet would be jRuby app in .war file, start with some guides of creating war files from Your apps:

- https://github.com/jruby/warbler
- http://jrubyist.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/using-jruby-warbler-rake-to-deploy-rails-apps-to-jboss/
- http://massivecoding.blogspot.com/2012/06/deploy-rails-3-application-to-google.html
- http://blog.headius.com/2008/08/zero-to-production-in-15-minutes.html